# Backend returned code 403, body was: Invalid CORS request

Tags: angular, spring-boot, nginx

In this problem, I deployed an application (backend with spring Boot) and (frontend with Angular) in VPS with Nginx.

In testing, I found an error:

```
POST https://www.example.com/X/XX 403

Backend returned code 403, body was:  Invalid CORS request
```

This is the security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/XX").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().denyAll()
                .and().httpBasic();

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.applyPermitDefaultValues();
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("POST"));
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("https://www.example.com"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

and the nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
server_name www.example.com;


        location / {
        root /var/www/html;  # Replace with the path to your Angular build output
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    }

location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:port;
        proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    }


    # SSL Config

if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

}
```

the frontend sends requests with the following APP URL:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,

  APPURL: "https://www.example.com/X"
};
```

what is wrong?
Is there any wrong with these configs?